# JPA-HIBERNATE : Eu entendi as conjuncoes e disjuncoes ? É isso mesmo?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Peguei umas apostilas de JPA e li alguns tutoriais na internet, mas estou ainda um pouco perdido com relação a disjunction e conjunction no JPA.

Pelo que eu entendi a conjuncao serve para agrupar condições com o "AND" do sql, já a disjuncao serve para agrupar condições com "OR". Estou certo? O material que pesquisei me parece muito confuso.

Tentei entao fazer o criteria gerar queries com o seguinte padrao:

```
WHERE (condicao1 = valor1 AND condicao2 = valor2) or (condicao3=valor3 and condicao4=valor4)
```

Entretanto eu nao tive sucesso com minha implementação:

```
 EntityManager em = JPAUtil.getEntityManager();

// Instanciar o BUILDER de criteria
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();

//Cria uma criteria query que trabalha com Conta
CriteriaQuery<Conta> cquery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Conta.class);

//Obter RAIZ da query que consulta da entidade CONTA
Root<Conta> root = cquery.from(Conta.class);

Path<String> titularPath = root.<String>get("titular");
Path<Integer> idPath = root.<Integer>get("id");
Path<String> numeroPath = root.<String>get("numero");
Path<String> bancoPath = root.<String>get("banco");

Predicate titularIgual = criteriaBuilder.like(titularPath, "M%");
Predicate idIgual = criteriaBuilder.equal(idPath, 1);
Predicate idDiferente = criteriaBuilder.equal(idPath, 500);     

//Conjuncao1 seria (idDiferente AND titularIgual) ???
Predicate conjuncao1 = criteriaBuilder.conjunction();
conjuncao1 = criteriaBuilder.and(conjuncao1,idDiferente);
conjuncao1 = criteriaBuilder.and(conjuncao1,titularIgual);

//Conjunao2 seria (idIgual AND titularIgual) ???
Predicate conjuncao2 = criteriaBuilder.conjunction();
conjuncao2 = criteriaBuilder.and(conjuncao2,idIgual);
conjuncao2 = criteriaBuilder.and(conjuncao2,titularIgual);

//Se minha logica estiver correta entao a disjuncao das duas conjuncoes deveria ser
// (idDiferente AND titularIgual) or (idIgual AND titularIgual) Não?
Predicate disjuncao = criteriaBuilder.disjunction();
disjuncao = criteriaBuilder.or(conjuncao1,conjuncao2);  


cquery.where(disjuncao);
TypedQuery<Conta> tQuery = em.createQuery(cquery);
List<Conta> contas = tQuery.getResultList();
```

Eu nao entendi o fato do Hibernate ter gerado a consulta abaixo:

```
where
1=1 
and conta0_.id=500 
and (
conta0_.titular like ?
) 
or 1=1 
and conta0_.id=1 
and (
conta0_.titular like ?
)
```

Isso nao faz sentido no meu entendimento de conjunction... eu acredito que ambas as condicoes : "conta.Id = 1 e conta.titular = ?" deveriam estar fora de parenteses ou ate mesmo estarem ambas sob o mesmo parentese.

Eu entendi direito essa historia de conjunction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Os operadores SQL seguem a seguinte ordem de precedência: `NOT` > `AND` > `OR`. Ou seja, primeiro são avaliadas as expressões com o operador `NOT`, em seguida `AND` e por último `OR` . Dessa forma, a consulta:

```
WHERE 
1=1 
AND conta.id = 500 
AND (conta.titular like ?)
OR
1=1 
AND conta.id = 1 
AND (conta.titular like ?)
```

É a mesma coisa que:

```
WHERE (
1=1 
AND conta.id = 500 
AND (conta.titular like ?))
OR (
1=1 
AND conta.id = 1 
AND (conta.titular like ?))
```

Sendo assim, os parênteses são desnecessários e o Hibernate não os adiciona a consulta.

Quanto aos parênteses presentes na sua consulta, eles são adicionados pelo Hibernate a uma expressão `LIKE` quando ela está junto ao operador `AND`. Eu ainda não sei/descobri o porquê do Hibernate fazer isso (caso descubra, voltarei e adicionarei a resposta).

Sobre as expressões `1=1`, elas são adicionadas a sua consulta nos seguintes trechos:

```
Predicate conjuncao1 = criteriaBuilder.conjunction();
```

E:

```
Predicate conjuncao2 = criteriaBuilder.conjunction();
```

Um trecho da sua `Criteria` com alguns comentários:

```
Predicate titularIgual = criteriaBuilder.like(titularPath, "M%");   //conta0_.titular like ?
Predicate idIgual = criteriaBuilder.equal(idPath, 1);               //conta0_.id=1 
Predicate idDiferente = criteriaBuilder.equal(idPath, 500);         //conta0_.id=500

Predicate conjuncao1 = criteriaBuilder.conjunction();               //1=1
conjuncao1 = criteriaBuilder.and(conjuncao1,idDiferente);           //1=1 AND conta0_.id=500
conjuncao1 = criteriaBuilder.and(conjuncao1,titularIgual);          //1=1 AND conta0_.id=500 AND (conta0_.titular like ?)

Predicate conjuncao2 = criteriaBuilder.conjunction();               //1=1
conjuncao2 = criteriaBuilder.and(conjuncao2,idIgual);               //1=1 AND conta0_.id=1 
conjuncao2 = criteriaBuilder.and(conjuncao2,titularIgual);          //1=1 AND conta0_.id=1 AND (conta0_.titular like ?)

Predicate disjuncao = criteriaBuilder.disjunction();                //0=1
                                                                    //Como você não a adiciona na criteriaBuilder.or abaixo
                                                                    //essa expressão não aparece na consulta

disjuncao = criteriaBuilder.or(conjuncao1,conjuncao2);              //1=1 AND conta0_.id=500 AND (conta0_.titular like ?) OR 
                                                                    //1=1 AND conta0_.id=1 AND (conta0_.titular like ?)
```

#### Edit:

Caso você queira que uma operação que normalmente não teria precedência ocorra antes das demais e, para isso, o uso dos parênteses seriam necessários, o Hibernate irá inseri-los na consulta. Exemplo:

```
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Conta> cquery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Conta.class);
Root<Conta> root = cquery.from(Conta.class);

Path<String> titularPath = root.<String>get("titular");
Path<Integer> idPath = root.<Integer>get("id");
Path<String> numeroPath = root.<String>get("numero");

Predicate titularIgual = criteriaBuilder.like(titularPath, "M%");
Predicate idIgual = criteriaBuilder.equal(idPath, 1);
Predicate idDiferente = criteriaBuilder.equal(idPath, 500);     ;  

cquery.where(criteriaBuilder.and(idDiferente, criteriaBuilder.or(idIgual, titularIgual)));

List<Conta> contas = em.createQuery(cquery).getResultList();
```

SQL gerado:

```
SELECT conta0_.id AS id1_0_,
       conta0_.titular AS titular2_0_
FROM Conta conta0_
WHERE conta0_.id=500
  AND (conta0_.id=1
       OR conta0_.titular LIKE ?)
```

Ou seja, nesse caso o `OR` será executado antes do `AND`.

Comment: Ok! Mas para finalizar... e se eu quisesse fazer uma condição composta com o conjunction, ele poderia ser usado para esse FIM? Como seria?

Comment: @CleitonRibeiro Se compreendi corretamente sua dúvida, o que você quer saber é: caso você queira que uma condição seja executada antes das demais e, para que isso ocorre, seja necessário que hajam os parênteses no SQL, o Hibernate vá inseri-los? Se for isso a resposta é sim. Editei minha resposta com um exemplo.

Comment: Grato, foi bastante esclarecedor!

Comment: Obrigado, Senhores! Os exemplos ajudaram bastante...